# $(...).nivoSlider is not a function

Tags: html

I am trying to add Nivoslider into my website, but it is not working. Help me please!
It is working locally, but not on my server. I looked at other responses and tried them too... Does it matter that I am using a censored server??

```
(index):30 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).nivoSlider is not a function
at (index):30
at dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
at i (jquery.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @   (index):30
dispatch    @   jquery.min.js:3
i   @   jquery.min.js:3
```

This is the error message shown.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
...

  <!-- Styles -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,500,600,700,800,900|Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  <script src="js/modernizr-2.7.1.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" />  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider(); 
}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <!--Pricing-->
    <section id="pricing" class="pad-lg">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row margin-40">
          <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
            <h2 class="white">Gallery</h2>

<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<img src="img/1.jpg" data-thumb="img/1.jpg" alt="" />
</div>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't have the same files on your server as you have locally. Make sure to upload all files of your local project to the server an make sure that the paths to the files are the same.
My guess would be that this file <`script src="jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` is not available on your server, that's why it can't find the function `nivoSlider()`

Comment: Did you check the other files and if all the paths are correct? If you take out the nivoSlider, does the rest of the jQuery stuff work?